# Is there a way a report can be generated automatically every day/week/month?

Tags: cognito-forms

Is there a way a report can be generated automatically every day/week/month that shows the details of the entries submitted that can be emailed automatically to a specific email address/addresses?

Answer (score 1):

I just verified with them, that there is no way to send such reports.

Although in a conversation with Jennifer from Cognito Forms, she did say that;

"I will bring this up to the team as a possible future feature."

So -- thumbs up.